# Clear graphics from JPanel with ActionListener

Tags: java, swing

My question is, how do I clear the graphics using my action listener and create a new set of graphics, by running through OtherPanel again?

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame
  {

   private OtherPanel panel;

       public MainFrame()
   {

        panel = new OtherPanel();
       }

   class OtherPanel extends JPanel 
   {
      private OtherPanel()
      {
    ...

      }

      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
          super.paintComponent(g);

          Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;            
              ....

          }

      private class ReloadListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
           }
        }

    }
```

Comment: This seems really trivial. What have you tried? In what way did it fail?

Comment: I now figured it out.  But I am not sure why I need to updateUI();

Comment: Don't use `updateUI()` for this; `panel.repaint()` should suffice. If not, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 4):

```
class OtherPanel extends JPanel 
{
    private boolean isReset;

    private OtherPanel()
    {
    ...
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(!isReset){
            //your painting code here
        }
    }

    public void setReset(boolean reset){
        isReset = reset;
    }

    private class ReloadListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            setReset(true);
            repaint();
        }

    }
}
```

All depends on how should a "reset" panel look like. I left just `super.paintComponent()` as the default looks, you might want to change that. Don't forget to add `setReset(false)` to your code somewhere when you want to paint something on the panel.

Answer (score -2):

```
private class ReloadListener implements ActionListener
 {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
       newPic();
       panel.updateUI();            

  }

   public MainFrame newPic()
   {

      return new MainFrame();
   }
 }
```

Comment: wrong: application code doesn't call updateUI - that method is for the exclusive use of the pluggable LAF mechanism